# minipar Package

Tags: packages

I got a `.tex` file that uses a package called `minipar`. I do not need it, but I'm not having anything on the internet about this package. Maybe it's old. Does anyone have more information?

The `minipar` package is called and used as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minipar}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipar}
Text on some thing.
\end{minipar}
\end{document}
```

The `.tex` file is a presentation summary of an event, and the `minipar` package appears to be useful for removing whitespace at the beginning of paragraphs. See [1] for an example.

[1] https://sec.sbfisica.org.br/eventos/enfmc/xli/sys/resumos/R0827-2.pdf

Comment: what does `minipar` do exactly? Most likely, it's functionality can be obtained with other packages etc.

Comment: I know the ```minipage``` package, but I did not see any ```minipar``` in chapter 2. It could be a private package. I updated the question. It seems to be useful for removing for removing whitespace at the beginning of paragraphs.

Comment: `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`

Comment: @GhostRider If it does anything except a fatal error mean that you have `minipar.sty` somewhere, then you can edit it, and at least you will see what exactly it does (macro definitiions,etc.) and probably also some help in comments (luckily even a URL to the manual).

Comment: There was a question in `comp.text.tex`  about minipar.sty ... in 1993. Effectively it seems a bit old. If the only effect is suppress the paragraph indentation, you can safely forget it and use `parskip` instead or simply set `\parindent` yourself as showed above.

Comment: According, that's an easy task.